# Выбор окончания, падежа

Tags: падежи, окончания

> В трёх из четырёх рук(ах) он держал по мечу.

В трёх **руках** из четырёх **рук**... Тогда, получается, правильно будет в трёх из четырёх **руках**?

Comment: Формально ошибки нет, но звучит коряво. Стилистичеки лучше "**в трёх руках из четырёх** (он держал)".

Comment: @Alex_ander, да, действительно. Видимо, именно из-за корявости, как вы сказали, я и не могла понять, что тут делать с руками))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, правильно ***В трёх из четырёх рук он держал по мечу.*** Существительное управляется предлогом ***из*** (чего? Род. падеж — ***рук***). Просто после первого числительного с предлогом ***в*** опускается это существительное. То есть можно написать: ***В трёх руках из четырёх он держал по мечу***.

*― В 2000 году, когда правительство проводило первый подобный конкурс, «Норильский никель» занял первые места **в трех из четырех номинаций***.[ Ольга Голодец: «Мы делаем ставку на рост своего персонала» // «Известия», 2002.12.15]

*Наверное, они отметят, что **в трех из четырех видов** фигурного катания мои ученики становились олимпийскими чемпионами и чемпионами мира*.[Виталий Мелик-Карамов, Татьяна Тарасова. Красавица и чудовище (1984-2001)]

*― А почему вы не можете жить **в одной из трех комнат**?* [Токарева Виктория. Своя правда // «Новый Мир», 2002]

*Следующая его жертва, если она вообще будет, – обязательно **в одной из трех** оставшихся **областей***. [Александра Маринина. Не мешайте палачу (1996)]

Comment: Ой, я про **из** даже и не подумала :/ Спасибо за примеры.

Comment: @Юлия Всегда пожалуйста :)